# Numpy cannot import a module _get_ndarray_c_version

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I would like to run `weave` in my `python2.7` code. But, when I run the code with `import weave`, I get an error of a module not found in numpy

I have a `numpy 1.16.0` installed, and this is running on my Ubuntu server.

Here is the error:

`from numpy.core.multiarray import _get_ndarray_c_version
ImportError: cannot import name _get_ndarray_c_version`

I have already tried reinstalling `numpy`, but it does not seem to help. Are there any ways to fix this?

Comment: Seems like not many people have experienced this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is due to an incompatibility between numpy1.16 and weave.

https://github.com/scipy/weave/issues/11

Try with an older version of numpy.

Comment: Hi @Toni - This could be a great answer.  Would you be so kind as to [edit] into your answer some of the relevant snippets from the link?  Consider reading through [answer] in regards to how defunct links can negate the quality of your answer.